# List of all labels with hyperlinks

Tags: labels, tocloft

I'm writing a document with several `\label{}` environments and I'm looking for an opportunity to generate a list of all of them at the beginning, something like this:

```
Label 1 ..... 1
Label 2 ..... 2
Label 3 ..... 4
```

And so on. I had a look at `tocloft` but couldn't find anything.

Comment: do you actually want to print the internal symbolic label for debugging (like `showkeys` package) or print the referencable counter saved in the label at that point. so after `\section{introduction}\label{xyz}`  do you want your list to have the section number **1** or the internal lablel `xyz` ?

Comment: It always helps to provide a complete small document, it simplifies testing answers and you could be explicit about the list you wanted to generate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

The label information is all in the aux file, so you can extract it something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\long\def\findlabel#1#2\findlabel{%
 \ifx\newlabel#1\lablist\expandafter{\the\lablist\showlabel#2}\fi}

%hyerref has 4 felds in each label culd use them but don't here
\def\showlabel#1#2{%
\par \noindent Label: \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}\dotfill \ref{#1} on page \pageref{#1}}

\newtoks\lablist
\newread\zz
\immediate\openin\zz=\jobname.aux
\loop
\ifeof\zz\else
\read\zz to \tmp
\expandafter\findlabel\tmp\relax\findlabel
\repeat
\begin{document}

\section*{Labels}

\the\lablist

\section{ho ho ho}\label{z}
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
\subsection{him hum hum}\label{zz}
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
\begin{equation}
1=2\label{q}
\end{equation}
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 

\begin{figure}

X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\
X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\
X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\
X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X\\X

\caption{figure figure figure}\label{ff}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Based on your solution, I created a package available from github https://github.com/NobbZ/listlbls , it is also available from CTAN http://ctan.org/pkg/listlbls.

Comment: In the meantime the package has become part of TeXlive and MiKTeX.