# How to retrieve order of zref's labels in the aux file

Tags: zref

I'm playing with the very intersting `zref` and I'm stumbling at one point, thanks to my insufficient expansion-fu, and perhaps someone may find this problem easier.

`zref` writes labels to the aux file with `\protected@write` (not `\immediate`) so that the labels get written there in the order the objects to which these labels refer to get shipped out (as far as I understand, if this presumption is wrong, just let me know, and disregard what follows). And I think I could use the "shipout order" of the labels to infer (at least an approximation of) the relative position of different labels on the page (which one comes before, which comes after). So I'm trying to retrieve the sequence of labels in the order which they occur in the aux file.

The information `zref` stores in the aux file goes under a macro named `\zref@newlabel`, which is defined as:

```latex
\def\ZREF@RefPrefix{Z@R}
\ZREF@Robust\edef\zref@newlabel{%
  \noexpand\@newl@bel{\ZREF@RefPrefix}%
}
```

(As far as my reading goes, for a current TeXLive, which is what I have here, `\ZREF@Robust` will be `\protected`).

My thought is that I could use (patch/hook/redefine) this macro to do what it is intended to do, and also feed a (L3) `clist` with the information I want.

However, `\zref@newlabel` is one of those "commands that look ahead" mentioned in `ltcmdhooks` documentation. Indeed, `\@newl@bel` receives 3 arguments, and `\zref@newlabel` just passes the first, the following two will be scanned ahead. As far as I can tell, that means using `ltcmdhooks` is not viable for the case. (Edit: As I found out later, `ltcmdhooks` is not viable for still another reason, the hooks are not actually available when the .aux file is read, they come only after `\begin{document}`).

I've tried to redefine it, but unfortunately, I can't control expansion appropriately, so the question here is how could I make such a redefinition properly.

This is a MWE which illustrates the situation, and includes my failed attempt:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[user]{zref}
\usepackage{hyperref}% just for \phantomsection

\usepackage{econlipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\clist_new:N \g__auxfile_labelseq_clist

% That's more or less what I'd like to do, but... I can't make it work.
% \cs_gset_protected:Npn \zref@newlabel #1#2 {
%   \clist_gput_right:Nn \g__zrefcheck_auxfile_labelseq_clist {#1}
%   \exp_not:N \@newl@bel {\ZREF@RefPrefix} {#1} {#2}
% }

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\zlabel{cha:chapter-1}

\econ[1]

\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering
  \caption{Figure 1}
  \zlabel{fig:figure-1}
\end{figure}

A reference to the figure ``above''~\zref{fig:figure-1}%
\phantomsection\zlabel{fig:figure-1:reference}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: sounds a bit odd. Why do you need to know the order? And why can't you store the info in the label, e.g. with a new counter?

Comment: I'm trying to get "the order in which the object to which the label refers to gets shipped out", if I just add a counter which is stepped in `\zlabel` (is that what you are suggesting?), I'd have the order in which the labels occur in the source. If you check the aux of the MWE, the label to `fig:figure-1:reference` occurs before the one `fig:figure-1`. This is inverted relative to the sequence they occur in the document, because of the float, of course. And it is that inversion I'm trying to capture. Is there any other way you know of?

Comment: Btw, @UlrikeFischer, `zref` is indeed pretty cool, thanks again for the tip. I do miss the `hyperref` support, but I'm having lots of fun with it.

Comment: Ah, complementing the first comment. I did try to hook into `\ZREF@label` by stepping a counter in the second argument of `\protected@write` (the same way `\ZREF@label` does it's stuff) to try to capture the "shipout sequence". And added that counter to a starred version of `\zref@newprop*{shipoutseq}`. However, for reasons I do not understand, all the steps of the counter would run once per page "en block", so that I missed precisely the information I wanted, which is the relative position within the page.

Comment: but why do you need to know the order?

Comment: Because I'd like to make a check when I refer to that figure and say that it is "above", so I'd like to know if it is actually above as displayed in the page.

Comment: well in this case I would use zsavepos.

Comment: I am using it too, and I think I reached decent results (though not quite using the `\zsavepos` macro, because I want to get the position of a regular `\zlabel`, again, at the position it occurs on the page, so if we wanted to use `\zsavepos` we'd have to hack `\caption`, not `\zlabel`). But it may fail in cases such as columns and so on. Anyway, are you saying the order labels in the aux file is useless? Or that "I'd better not" try to retrieve it this way? I think it makes sense, but...

Comment: no the order is not useless, but you are creating (or would without the syntax errors) a quite long clist and then want to inspect it only to get the relation of two labels. That doesn't sound very efficient.

Comment: Well, in a regular document, even in a large one, this list may get to the hundreds, let's say. Would that be too much? Would that "exceed TeX capacity"? Besides, I'm not trying just to get the relation between two labels, I'm trying to be able to check any reference relative to it's label. I'd say it's pretty useful. To my knowledge, not even `varioref` has a solution to that. I'd be willing to pay the computational price (if it works, and if there's no equivalent better alternative). Anyway, at this point I'm at a "playing with stuff" stage. I'd like to try this.

Comment: well you are missing \makeatletter, and you are overdoing in the definitions. Also I would use a seq and not a clist. something like `\cs_gset_protected:Npn \zref@newlabel #1#2 {
   \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__zrefcheck_auxfile_labelseq_seq {#1}
   \@newl@bel {Z@R} {#1} {#2}}`.

Comment: Oh, damn! I was playing in a package file with `\ProvidesExplPackage` and completely forgot `\makeatletter` when transposing things to the MWE, sorry. But, your definition does work. Thank you very much! If you'd like to convert it to an answer, I'd happily accept it.  :-)

Comment: And @UlrikeFischer, in the interests of efficiency, I've mapped the result *once* after `begindocument` to a property list, so that I can retrieve the index pretty much as I would extract a zlabel's property value every time I want to compare any two labels.

Comment: @gusbrs About hyperref support: With hyperref loaded, `\label` also writes the name of the last named destination placed into the .pdf-file and the heading of the last section or the like. The further is in `\@currentHref`. The latter is in `\@currentlabelname`. If loading both hyperref and zref you can use `\@currentHref`/`\@currentlabelname` for new zref-properties and this way bring info about destination-names/sections into zref-labels. Then you can easily retrieve this info for defining your own zref-referencing-commands that create hyperlinks. But I wouldn't do this...

Comment: @gusbrs ... But I wouldn't do this: labels created by the `\label`-command and labels created by zref may have the same name. Therefore it might be more easy to write commands that create both a normal label (bringing along hyperref-functionality) and a zref-label at the same time.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I did find some things about `zref`'s `hyperref` support, since I commented. It is actually viable, even if somewhat bare-bones, out of the box. `zref`'s documentation states about the hyperref module "UNFINISHED :-(" (literally that). However, the `anchor` property is implemented! So, if you do load the module, you get the anchor in the mainlist. And you can build a link to that with `hyperref`'s `\hyperlink`. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ulrike's suggestion in the comments ([How to retrieve order of zref's labels in the aux file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604265/how-to-retrieve-order-of-zrefs-labels-in-the-aux-file?noredirect=1#comment1515359_604265)) was good, and indeed works, but it involves hard-coding `\ZREF@RefPrefix` in the redefinition. While this should be indeed harmless in this case, I still put some further thought on the matter, and eventually came to the following:

```latex
\seq_new:N \g__zrefcheck_auxfile_labelseq_seq

\ZREF@Robust\edef\zref@newlabel#1{
  \noexpand\seq_gput_right:Nn \noexpand\g__zrefcheck_auxfile_labelseq_seq {#1}
  \noexpand\@newl@bel{\ZREF@RefPrefix}{#1}
}
```

As far as I can tell, this would behave in a really equivalent way as the original (plus the added code, of course). (It seems I am learning something in the process  ;-)

However, in the meantime, I found out I'm certainly not the only one interested in the list of existing labels. At least two packages on CTAN also retrieve this information: `crossreftools` and `listlbls`. The first one constructs a special toc (with corresponding file) for the purpose, while the latter reads the .aux file directly.

`listlbls` was based on an answer by David Carlisle ([List of all labels with hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147705/105447)) here on TeX.SX. I thought this was a good approach, because it does not require redefining any internals or additional infrastructure. The package, alas, is made to work with regular labels, not those of `zref`, and also does not really expose the information in a retrievable way (as far as I could tell). So I cooked an adapted version of it (a poor man's version at that):

```latex
\seq_new:N \g__zrefcheck_auxfile_labelseq_seq

\tl_set:Nn \g_tmpa_tl { \c_sys_jobname_str .aux }
\file_if_exist:nT { \g_tmpa_tl }
  {
    \ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior { \g_tmpa_tl }
    \group_begin:
      \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_ior
        {
          \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \zref@newlabel }
          \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \tl_item:nn {#1} { 1 } }
          \tl_if_eq:NNT \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl
            {
              \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_item:nn {#1} { 2 } }
              \seq_gput_right:NV \g__zrefcheck_auxfile_labelseq_seq \l_tmpa_tl
            }
        }
    \group_end:
    \ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can patch `\zref@newlabel` to count labels, to add number and name of a label to an expl3-sequence, to add the number of a label as value of the property `labelnumber` to the label itself, and to do a `\@newl@bel` with different prefix for mapping from the number of a zref-label to its name:

```latex
\errorcontextlines=10000

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[user]{zref}
\usepackage{atveryend}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\zref@newprop{labelnumber}{0}%
\newcommand*\labelcount{0}%
\ZREF@Robust\edef\zref@newlabel{%
  \xdef\noexpand\labelcount{\noexpand\number\numexpr\noexpand\labelcount+1\relax}%
  \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\AddElementAndCallNewlabel\noexpand\expandafter{\noexpand\labelcount}{\ZREF@RefPrefix}%
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\AddElementAndCallNewlabel {mmmm} {
   % #1 = number of label
   % #2 \@newl@bel-prefix
   % #3 name of label
   % #4 property-list of label
   \__MyStuff_AddElement:nn{#1}{#3}
   \@newl@bel{MYmapping}{#1}{#3}
   \@newl@bel{#2}{#3}{#4\labelnumber{#1}}
}
\newcommand\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber[2]{
   % #1 = number of label
   % #2 = tokens in case no label name is mapped to number of label
   \romannumeral
   \cs_if_exist:cTF{MYmapping@#1}
                   { \exp_args:Nc \use_ii_i:nn 
                                  {MYmapping@#1}
                                  {\exp_args:No \use_ii_i:nn}{\UD@stopromannumeral} }
                   {\UD@stopromannumeral#2}
}
% Error-message in case no label name is mapped to number of label;
% like zref@refused, but for prefix MYmapping instead of \ZREF@RefPrefix=Z@R:
\NewDocumentCommand\LabelNumberNotMapped{m}{
   % #1 = term denoting number of label
  \protect\G@refundefinedtrue\@latex@warning {No~zref-label~is~mapped~to~number~`#1'~on~page~\thepage}
}
\makeatother
\seq_new:N \g__zrefcheck_auxfile_labelseq_seq
\cs_new:Nn \__MyStuff_AddElement:nn {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__zrefcheck_auxfile_labelseq_seq {{#1}{#2}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \ListOfZrefLabels {} {%
  \seq_map_function:NN \g__zrefcheck_auxfile_labelseq_seq \__MyStuff_PrintElement:n
}
\cs_new:Nn \__MyStuff_PrintElement:n {
  \__MyStuff_PrintElement:nn #1
}
\cs_new:Nn \__MyStuff_PrintElement:nn{
  #1.\nobreakspace#2,~
}
\AfterLastShipout{\xdef\labelcount{0}\cs_set:Nn \__MyStuff_AddElement:nn {}}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter

% For the sake of having fun define a loop which prints the names of all labels defined
% before and after the label specified as argument:

\@ifdefinable\gobbletorelax{\long\def\gobbletorelax#1\relax{}}%
\@ifdefinable\delivertorelax{\long\def\delivertorelax#1\relax{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherRelax[1]{%
  \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\gobbletorelax#1\relax}$%
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
  {%
     \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral\delivertorelax\UD@stopromannumeral#1}$%
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
     {\@firstoftwo}%
  }%
  {\@secondoftwo}%
}%
\newcommand\AllPreceedingAndFollowingLabels[2]{%
   \romannumeral
   \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{%
     \AllSubSequentLabelsLoop{#1}{%
        \AllSubSequentLabelsLoop{#1}%
                                {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\@firstofone}%
                                {+}%
     }{-}{\textbf{#1}}%
   }%
}%
\newcommand\jointhem[4]{\AllSubSequentLabelsLoop{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4, #1}}%
\newcommand\jointhemexchanged[4]{\AllSubSequentLabelsLoop{#1}{#2}{#3}{#1, #4}}%
\newcommand\AllSubSequentLabelsLoop[4]{%
  % #1 = name of label.
  % #2 = tokens to aplly to the list of label-names gathered so far when the loop is done.
  % #3 = +/- ; marker for obtaining name of following/previous label.
  % #4 = list of label-names gathered so far.
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherRelax
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{%
      \number\numexpr\zref@extractdefault{#1}{labelnumber}{-2}#31\relax
    }{\relax}%
  }%
  {#2{#4}}%
  {%
    \ifx#3-%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\jointhemexchanged}%
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\jointhem}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{%
        \number\numexpr\zref@extractdefault{#1}{labelnumber}{-2}#31\relax
      }{\relax}%
    }{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  }%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hrulefill

Some text.

\hrulefill

\ListOfZrefLabels

\hrulefill

\makeatletter

LabelUndef has number \zref@extractdefault{LabelUndef}{labelnumber}{\zref@refused{LabelUndef}\textsf{-not available-}}%

LabelA has number \zref@extractdefault{LabelA}{labelnumber}{\zref@refused{LabelA}\textsf{-not available-}}%

LabelB has number \zref@extractdefault{LabelB}{labelnumber}{\zref@refused{LabelB}\textsf{-not available-}}%

LabelC has number \zref@extractdefault{LabelC}{labelnumber}{\zref@refused{LabelC}\textsf{-not available-}}%

LabelD has number \zref@extractdefault{LabelD}{labelnumber}{\zref@refused{LabelD}\textsf{-not available-}}%

LabelE has number \zref@extractdefault{LabelE}{labelnumber}{\zref@refused{LabelE}\textsf{-not available-}}%

\hrulefill

The name of label number 0 is 
\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{0}{\LabelNumberNotMapped{0}\textsf{-not available-}}

The name of label number 1 is 
\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{1}{\LabelNumberNotMapped{1}\textsf{-not available-}}

The name of label number 2 is 
\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{2}{\LabelNumberNotMapped{2}\textsf{-not available-}}

The name of label number 3 is 
\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{3}{\LabelNumberNotMapped{3}\textsf{-not available-}}

The name of label number 4 is 
\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{4}{\LabelNumberNotMapped{4}\textsf{-not available-}}

The name of label number 5 is 
\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{5}{\LabelNumberNotMapped{5}\textsf{-not available-}}

The name of label number 6 is 
\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{6}{\LabelNumberNotMapped{6}\textsf{-not available-}}

The name of label number W is 
\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{W}{\LabelNumberNotMapped{W}\textsf{-not available-}}

The name of the label which was placed after LabelC is
\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{%
  \number\numexpr\zref@extractdefault{LabelC}{labelnumber}{-2}+1\relax
}{\LabelNumberNotMapped{%
    <Number of LabelC>+1
  }%
  \textsf{-not available-}%
}

The name of the label which was placed after LabelE is
\GetLabelNameFromLabelNumber{%
  \number\numexpr\zref@extractdefault{LabelE}{labelnumber}{-2}+1\relax
}{\LabelNumberNotMapped{%
    <Number of LabelE>+1
  }%
  \textsf{-not available-}%
}


\hrulefill

\AllPreceedingAndFollowingLabels{LabelUndef}{\zref@refused{LabelUndef}\textsf{-not available-}}%

\AllPreceedingAndFollowingLabels{LabelA}{\zref@refused{LabelA}\textsf{-not available-}}%

\AllPreceedingAndFollowingLabels{LabelB}{\zref@refused{LabelB}\textsf{-not available-}}%

\AllPreceedingAndFollowingLabels{LabelC}{\zref@refused{LabelC}\textsf{-not available-}}%

\AllPreceedingAndFollowingLabels{LabelD}{\zref@refused{LabelD}\textsf{-not available-}}%

\AllPreceedingAndFollowingLabels{LabelE}{\zref@refused{LabelE}\textsf{-not available-}}%

\hrulefill

\zref@labelbylist{LabelA}{main}%

\zref@labelbylist{LabelB}{main}%

\zref@labelbylist{LabelC}{main}%

\zref@labelbylist{LabelD}{main}%

\zref@labelbylist{LabelE}{main}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! Thank you! So you got hooked on the problem too. ;-)  On my side, I'm post processing the sequence to a proplist, to be able to query it, but this approach of yours is nice too. I did go with reading the .aux file though, since not having to tamper with the internals is a big plus here, in my view.